# help isolating why MacBookPro Late-2013 15in Retina with HighSiera randomly shuts down?

Tags: high-sierra, crash, launchd, shutdown

While using my MacBook Pro and often while using chrome, my macbook does dark for a sec and then the computer shuts down. I am not sure if this is related to chrome but I tried:

1. Resting SMC
2. Running Diagnostics which resulted in no findings.
3. Installed all updates.

I am trying to see if this is a hardware issue or a software issue, I am leaning toward the latter.

Here is the system log during the window when the issue occurd
[image]
Any help is appreciated:

Here are the shutdown logs from shortly before and after:

```
2021-02-11 13:37:45 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context75.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:45  id:0x0x500008042 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:45 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context75.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:45  id:0x0x100008041 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context71.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:51  id:0x0x500008036 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context71.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:51  id:0x0x100008035 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context72.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:51  id:0x0x50000803a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context72.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:51  id:0x0x100008039 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context77.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:49  id:0x0x500008062 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context77.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:49  id:0x0x100008061 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context78.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:49  id:0x0x500008066 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context78.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:49  id:0x0x100008065 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context82.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:43  id:0x0x500008077 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context82.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:43  id:0x0x100008076 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.audio.context83.preventuseridledisplaysleep" 00:04:43  id:0x0x50000807b [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:50 -0500 Assertions            PID 160(coreaudiod) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "com.apple.audio.context83.preventuseridlesleep" 00:04:43  id:0x0x10000807a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:52 -0500 Assertions            PID 928(Software Update) Created MaintenanceWake "com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.RootModeInstaller" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000080c6 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:37:52 -0500 Assertions            PID 928(Software Update) Created PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep "com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.RootModeInstaller.DisplayAwake" 00:00:00  id:0x0x5000080c7 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:38:10 -0500 Assertions            Summary- [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp] Using AC(Charge: 99)          
2021-02-11 13:40:25 -0500 Assertions            PID 244(backupd) ClientDied PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Time Machine backup" 00:07:43  id:0x0x100008005 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:40:25 -0500 Assertions            PID 244(backupd) ClientDied BackgroundTask "Time Machine backup" 00:07:43  id:0x0xb00008004 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:42:11 -0500 Assertions            PID 864(system_installd) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Installing Software (com.apple.PackageKit.installd.commit)" 00:03:13  id:0x0x1000080d8 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
2021-02-11 13:42:33 -0500 Assertions            PID 627(softwareupdated) Released PreventUserIdleSystemSleep "Updating Software (com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.Session)" 00:04:09  id:0x0x1000080d7 [System: PrevIdle PrevDisp DeclUser SRPrevSleep kCPU kDisp]          
Sleep/Wakes since boot at 2021-02-11 13:32:38 -0500 :0   Dark Wake Count in this sleep cycle:3
```

output of:
`log show --style syslog --last 20m | egrep shutdown\ cause | awk -F')' '{print substr($0,1,19), $NF}'`

```
2021-02-12 16:08:22  Previous shutdown cause: -128
2021-02-12 16:08:38 2021-02-12 16:08:38.087188-0500  localhost DumpPanic[66]: found previous shutdown cause -128
```

Comment: Do you see a panic log from the time this occurred in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`?

Comment: I see a number of logs from today related to the following apps: docker, webstorem, phpstrom.. all heavy on memory applications.

Comment: I’m specifically looking for logs that have the `.panic` file extension. Make sure to sort by date so you’re seeing the one from the time this occurred.

Comment: no I do not see any. I saw a thread on macrumors that similar errors might be related to video card malfunction. Wonder how i can verify this theory.

Comment: Next step is to check the shutdown cause then. Run `$ pmset -g log` in *Terminal* and paste the log from shortly before to shortly after the timestamp of the most recent failure.

Comment: thanks you posted the logs in the question above

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more specific. Let’s just look at `$ pmset -g log | grep -C 10 ShutdownCause | tail -n 30`

Comment: This did not result in any output but this did `log show --style syslog --last 20m | egrep shutdown\ cause | awk -F')' '{print substr($0,1,19), $NF} ' ` From: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7750562

Comment: from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/413463/help-isolating-why-macbookpro-late-2013-retina-with-highsiera-randomly-shuts-dow#413463: -128 is probably related to memory or gpu. but cannot tell if software or hardware

Comment: Does this happen only on battery power or when you’re plugged into AC as well?

Comment: Also do you have the 13” or the 15” MBP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119684/discussion-between-smarty-and-pion).

Answer (score 1):

`-128` is a catch-all shutdown cause in SMC. It’s unfortunately not specific enough to suggest a particular line of investigation. From experience, a couple of things to look for would be:

1. Poor battery health can cause voltage sag under high workload and leads to a brownout. Given that you’ve mentioned in chat that this happens under AC power, this is unlikely. This bears reconfirmation so please **try running only on AC power** for a while to see if the shutdown recurs.
2. The GPU, especially the discrete GPU, has sometimes been at the root cause. *Chrome* is an inefficient piece of code and is likely causing utilization spikes. The may force frequent switching between integrated and discrete graphics on systems with discrete GPUs, which yours has. It’s possible that this trips a race condition in the GPU MUX. We can disable the switching by forcing DG always on: Use the *Energy Saver* system preference pane to disable “**Automatic graphics switching**”.
3. By the same token as #2, we can disable accelerated graphics entirely. This requires either running in Safe Mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot) or using a third-party utility, such as [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/). Now, I don’t use Chrome myself (and I strongly urge others not to, for reasons of performance, stability, security, and privacy) but I did come across [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/325004/404917) that would be a good switch to toggle as part of your experiment.

Comment: Thanks, so far I have done the following and not sure which one may have fixed (masked) the problem: 1) `pmset -a gpuswitch 0` 2) drained the battery as suggested on some thread. 3) Execluded/and re-included hard drive and certain directory in spotlight indexing, 4) upgraded to moave (but the problem persisted with this). I suspect 1,2 to be likely candidate of this.

Comment: `pmset -a gpuswitch 0` is the command-line equivalent of disabling automatic graphics switching which I mentioned above. We can test if that was the actual workaround by reenabling it (either by specifying `1` instead of `0` or in Energy Saver prefs). Note that you are currently disabling it on both AC and battery power (`-a`).